# what is the difference between index.ctp and view.ctp in cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

what is the difference between index.ctp and view.ctp in cakephp 3.x ?

Comment: @madalinivascu  oww...many many thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

index.ctp and view.ctp both are 2 different view files based on the requirement will use these files.

CakePHP view files are written in plain PHP and have a default extension of .ctp (CakePHP Template). These files contain all the presentational logic needed to get the data it received from the controller in a format that is ready for the audience you’re serving to.

refer to: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#view-templates

Answer (score 0):

Normally the index view will list all of the rows of a specific table. The view shows the details of an entity from the index view. That is the general use but those can be modified to do just about anything.